# How do you do interprocess communication (IPC) in Rust?

Tags: ipc, rust

Is there part of the standard library for this?

I've been digging around, but I can't see anything immediately obvious that implements it, or anything on `Process` that would let you do this?

Did I miss it? Or do I have to do some C-wrapper work for this functionality?

(if so, is it 'safe' to serialize an object that is `Send` and pass it another process, then deserialize it there? That's what `Send` means right?)

Comment: TCP and UDP sockets are available, which in my mind allows for communicating between processes. Or do you mean a specific type of IPC? Maybe there are something existing you want to interoperate with? Are there any examples of IPC that you have in mind?

Answer (score 20):

There is no single blessed way to do interprocess communication in Rust. You will need to use whatever technology you want: pipes, bare sockets (TCP or UDP), shared memory, nanomsg/ZeroMQ, whatever.

Also `Send` does not mean that you can serialize an object of a type which implements it and send to another process. It means that the data can be safely sent to another *thread* (e.g. it does not contain any references into the stack of the source thread), and it is not related to serialization.

For example, one of the basic forms of IPC are stdin/stdout pipes between parent and child processes. `Process` API allows you to send and receive data through these pipes:

```
use std::io::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut p = Command::new("tr").arg("a-z").arg("A-Z").spawn().unwrap();

    {
        let mut p_stdin = p.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
        p_stdin.write_str("hello world").unwrap();
    }
    p.wait().unwrap().success();

    let response = p.stdout.as_mut().unwrap().read_to_string().unwrap();
    println!("Responded: {}", response);
}
```

Or you can use sockets, but the example would be quite large. You can find sockets API documentation [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/).

Comment: Pipes or shared memory are the standard IPC mechanisms I'm referring to.

Comment: 9 years later: package is now `std::process::Command`. `write_str` and `read_to_string`: methods not found. Etc.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you look at the [`plibsys` library](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys). A trivial bindgen [binding is available](https://github.com/shadowmint/rust-plibsys-sys) as a starting point for anyone who wants to write an idiomatic Rust binding.

If all you're after is simple, practical IPC in Rust, falling back to the C IPC mechanisms is currently the only real solution; plibsys is simply a convenient portable high level C API to do that with.